# How many runs of Java program do we need to warm-up the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, startup, measurement, warm-up

Suppose I have a Java program `Test.class`. I want to measure its execution time. I wrote a wrapper to do this as below:

```
class RunTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long sum = 0;
        int iterations = 20;
        int warmupNum = 10;

        for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++){

            long start = System.nanoTime();
            Test.main(args);
            long end = System.nanoTime();

            if( i > warmupNum )
              sum += end - start;
        }

       System.out.println("ave: "+sum/(iterations-warmupNum));
    }
}
```

Here how to choose `warmupNum`, the larger the better? How large is enough? Is this a "standard/common" way to measure Java program's performance?

Comment: 10,000 is the default value before the JIT starts doing its job. You might be interested in reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: @assylias You are saying the 10000 is the number of repetitions for optimizing a method, right? Here, I want to know of warmup iterations of program to get a stable execution time.

Comment: yes - the JIT will start compiling a method after it's been called 10,000 times. You can change that value with the parameters you pass to the JVM but I can't find it right now.

Comment: [this gives more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4626779/829571) - 10000 is in server mode - it seems to be 1500 in client mode.

Comment: @JackWM Accept my answer if I've answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) than creating your own micro-benchmark utility.

[How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java/4480774#4480774)